# change flowplayer buffering size

Tags: files

I install video module and play videos by `flowplayer`,and in video module general settings  I check buffering video on page load , when the page load video starting to buffer, but will it not play (when click on play icon) till all video fill buffer  completely, ( I also uncheck buffering video on page load,then video not buffered in page load, but when I click on play video it start to buffer, but not play the video till the video completely buffered).
as example you can see [this video here](http://cinemagram.ir/video/32169)

I didn't find any option to set buffering size, **I want to know how can I set buffering size?** as example want to set it  to 5 sec,it is mean every 5 second that video buffered it start to play that 5 sec .

Comment: Why is `check buffering video on page load` marked as code? is it some setting you turned on? Some function you call? It got me confused. Please remove code ticks from things that are not code, and add a bit of explanation to things that are.

Comment: @Mołot it is a check box in video module general settings